# Webpack 4 Production Build not loading Images and CSS

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

I am new to webpack so I am facing few issues below:

My [GitHub](https://github.com/rahul-naik/webpack-es6) repo

**1. Here is the Problem :**

My Webpack file :

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // Require  html-webpack-plugin plugin

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + "/src/app/index.js", // webpack entry point. Module to start building dependency graph
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist', // Folder to store generated bundle
    filename: 'bundle.js',  // Name of generated bundle after build
    publicPath: '/' // public URL of the output directory when referenced in a browser
  },
  module: {  // where we defined file patterns and their loaders
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader', // inject CSS to page
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run post css actions
          options: {
            plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
              return [
                require('autoprefixer')
              ];
            }
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [  // Array of plugins to apply to build chunk
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/src/public/index.html",
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ],
  devServer: {  // configuration for webpack-dev-server
    contentBase: './src/public',  //source of static assets
    port: 7700, // port to run dev-server
  }
};
```

my folder structure :

[image: My Folder Strucure]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --history-api-fallback --inline --progress",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.6.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run start` I can see my application on browser with all CSS and Imagesloaded.

When I run `npm run build` I can see `dist` folder however When I run index.html from dist folder; I can't see any images and CSS loaded.
What I am doing wrong here?

Also I am building Static website so I will be having multiple HTML files along side e.g. home.html etc. so how can i link those pages accordingly?

Comment: How do you run `index.html` in browser? In order to serve static assets to your application you should run an HTTP server from your `dist` folder.

Comment: i directly opened it in browser..do I need to host that in sever ? like tomcat and so ?

Comment: @AndreaCarraro even I cant see Images folder generated in dist !

Comment: If you have python installed, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` is a quick solution to run a test HTTP server.

Comment: That I did...but main problem persist..no image folder in dist and no css getting applied

Comment: Do you import images from SASS files?

Comment: No I havent..let me push my code to github..shall post link here

Comment: @AndreaCarraro https://github.com/rahul-naik/webpack-es6 this is what I have done till now

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url) Sass does not provide url rewriting, and all `url(...)`-like imports should be relative to the entry-file.

There is a specific Webpack plugin to automate that: [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader).

It's meant to be configured just after `sass-loader` with source map enabled.

```
{
    test: /\.(scss)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'style-loader',
    }, {
        loader: 'css-loader',
    }, {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            plugins: function() {
                return [
                    require('autoprefixer')
                ];
            }
        }
    }, {
        loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
    },
    {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        }
    }]
},
```

Comment: Followed above...However problem is still there...I am talking about static image folder not getting generated in dist folder. neither any CSS getting applied in production build. Its something else..not related to request-url-loader

Comment: Your import entrypoint file `src/app/index.js` imports a single `.scss` file. Webpack will consider only those files included in the dependencies tree of your entrypoint.

Comment: But on webpack-dev-server it's working ! ...when I build it in prod it's not....can you clone the repo and check once ?

Comment: And also required CSS is their in app.scss which is imported in entry point!

Answer (score 0):

When you develop your folder structure with a separate css folder like this:

```
index.html
css/main.css
```

You could `forget` to use that same relative path when building the project for production. In my case, I forgot to add the `css/` prefix to the file name.

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: 'css/main.css',
}),
```

The css file became `main.css` but the JS entry point was looking for `css/main.css`

```js
import '../css/main.css'
```